# When to use "thanks for stopping by"?

Tags: sentence-usage, formality

Is "thanks for stopping by" used for brief visits? And when can we use it, at the beginning or at the end of the visit?

Is it informal? If yes, what can we use instead to convey a formal impression, for both speaking and writing.

Answer (score 3):

**Thanks for stopping by** is very versatile. You can use it at the beginning of the visit:

> Come on in, thanks for stopping by.

And at the end of the visit:

> I really enjoyed our visit. Thanks for stopping by.

It's informal, in that it's usually something that's said between friends or acquaintances, but you could use it in a formal setting, too. A slightly more formal phrase might be:

> Thank you for coming.

Comment: Would you write on a web page "thank you for stopping by"?

Comment: You might, but we usually say that people visit web pages. So you would more often say "thanks for visiting."

Comment: I would say if you were going for a "chummy" feel on the webpage you could very well say that "well thanks for stopping by and reading my story". This answer is Brit Eng. in case that makes a difference

Comment: No, the same is true in American English. I would agree with that.